# RxJS and optional inner query

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have a kind of web form which has 2 parts (master and optional child) and want to save the form values

A first call is for master data. The call result is used as a parameter for second call. But in some cases we don't need to save child part.

In the end of saving in the subscribe section I want to show "Success" message with one field from the first call result. I mean we can have one or two calls but show the success message when both of them completed

*Master Data Call -> Child Data Call (optional) -> Success message*

How to implement the behaviour using RxJS in a proper way?

**Addition:**

Based on comments I created an example here:
https://rxjs.rxplayground.com/

```
var master = from([1,2])
var child = of(10)

master.pipe(concatMap(m=>(m==1)?child:EMPTY)).subscribe(res=>console.log(res))
```

*(shows 10 but should be 1,2)*

Try to change "master" value. In any case log output should match the master. Also it would be nice to avoid "of(m)" inside of concatMap call

**One more addition:**

I tried this but not sure that it is the best solution

```
var master = from([1,2]);
var child = of("*");

master.pipe(
  mergeMap(m => (m  === 1 ? child.pipe(mapTo(m)) : of(m)))
).subscribe(console.log);
```

*(shows 1,2)*

Comment: We can do like something - Assuming `master` and `Child` returning `Observable` - `master.pipe(concatMap((masterData) => condition ? child : Empty))`

Comment: I only need single "masterData" result in subscriber but wait when (optional) child is completed. Does concatMap works in this way?

Comment: yes..`concatMap` will not subscribe to next inner observable until previous one completes.So using ` concatMap` `child` will be executed once master gets completed

Comment: posted what I tried

Answer (score 0):

I was saying this,just check once

```ts
import { from, of } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const master$ = from([1, 2, 3, 4]);
const child$ = of(20);
// const child$ = () => console.log("child called");

master$
  .pipe(
    concatMap((masterData) => {
      if (masterData % 2 === 0) {
        child$;
        // child$(); // if you want to check,child is being  called or not
      }
      return of(masterData);
    })
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: using `RxJs 6+`

Comment: If you are using `RxJs 5+` then use `of()` in place of `EMPTY`

Comment: 1. try to change "child" to "of("*") because child call gives me it's own result
2. your example should give me [1,2,3,4] in log because I always need the master result in subscriber even if child should be passed

Comment: So You do need `child$` response in subscribe ?

Comment: updated my answer,check it

Answer (score 0):

This solution does exactly what I need

```
var master = from([1,2]);
var child = of("*");

master.pipe(
  mergeMap(m => (m  === 1 ? child.pipe(mapTo(m)) : of(m)))
).subscribe(console.log);
```

(shows 1,2)